# Как правильно настроить сервер GIT

Tags: git, настройка, репозиторий

Есть задача создать сервер гит на котором будут хранится файлы разработчиков. 
Сервер:

> - UBUNTU SERVER

Клиенты:

> - Windows

Есть три групы разработчиков:

> - groupA
> - groupB
> - groupC

Необходимо на сервере (GIT) создать 3 репозитория:

> - repoA
> - repoB
> - repoC

Требования:

1. Разработчики заливают все свои файлы на сервер (GIT)
2. Разработчики могут скопировать все файлы с сервера (GIT)
3. Разработчики вносят изменения в файлы и заливают все на сервер (GIT)

Так вот вопрос - на сервере нужно создавать три `bare` репозитория? Или можно просто создать три папки (на сервере), инициализировать их командой `git init` и сделать в эти папки `push` с клиентского компьютера (что-бы проект с компьютера клиента оказался на сервере)? Просто я не понимаю принцип работы: что есть bare и что есть обычный репозиторий? Мне нужно что бы файлы разработчиков были как у них локально так и на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общее правило: на каждый проект по одному репозиторию. Если три команды работают над одним кодом, то им нужен один репозиторий. Если над тремя разными (даже работающими во взаимодействии) — три репозитория.

Голый (bare) репозиторий отличается от обычного тем, что в нем хранятся только внутренние файлы хранилища Git, но не обычные файлы в рабочей области проекта. Как правило, голый репозиторий используется в качестве удаленного и изменения на нем вносятся только с помощью команды `push` с одного из подключенных к нему локальных.

Папка с bare репозиторием, как правило, называется `name.git`

Обычный репозиторий, напротив, строится вокруг реальных файлов в файловой системе. Так же как и в bare, в нем есть хранилище файлов Git, в папке `.git`. Изменения в такой репозиторий вносятся с помощью создания новых коммитов, а также с помощью скачивания изменений из удаленного репозитория с помощью `fetch` или `pull`.

Для каждой команды можно проделать примерно такой путь:

1. Создается удаленный bare-репозиторий
2. Один разработчик инициализирует репозиторий на своей машине и добавляет файлы проекта.

   ```
   git init
   touch .gitignore
   open .gitignore # перечислить файлы и папки, которые не подлежат контролю версий
   git add .
   git commit -m'first commit'
   ```
3. Разработчик подключает удаленный репозиторий и заливает свой проект.

   ```
   git remote add origin ....
   git push -u origin master
   ```
4. Остальные клонируют с удаленного репозитория. Теперь у всех есть локальные репозитории, подключенные к центральному.

   ```
   git clone ...
   ```

Ещё вам обязательно нужно будет определить правила, по которым разработчики создают ветки, кто может делать слияние в основную ветку (`master`), и т.п. Достаточно популярной и гибкой моделью работы явлется [git-flow](/questions/tagged/git-flow), информацию и полезные ссылки можно найти в [описании этой метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-flow/info).

> Мне нужно что бы файлы разработчиков были как у них локально так и на сервере.

Здесь поподробнее. Вам нужно развертывание сайта? Или вы хотите их вручную править на сервере?

Comment: Из удалённого -- скорее `fetch` или `pull`.

Comment: @D-side: да, конечно, опечатался. Спасибо, что заметили.

Comment: Хочу что бы например: приходит новый разработчик и клонируя определенный репозиторий себе на комп получает все файлы разработки (тоесть все файлы разработки должны быть не только у разработчиков но и на сервере). Это реально?

Comment: Уточню: У меня на локальной машине есть папка с проектом. Я хочу его каким то образом запулить на сервер GIT что бы мои новые помошники могли себе его склонировать что-то добавить, поменять и т.д. и опять запулить на сервер откуда я благополучно склонирую и тоже что то поменяю и добавлю и тоже запулю на сервер. Хочу сто бы на сервере всегда был актуальный проект. Как это сделать?

Comment: @MARKSIST: да, именно так и будет работать эта схема. Если хотите, можем сегодня вечером вместе потестировать её. Можно на каком-нибудь открытом сервере вроде GitHub, можно на вашем. Объясню, что и как работает.

Comment: @MARKSIST: часа через 3-4 буду в этом чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so