# Переназначить ветку HEAD

Tags: git

Склонировал git с сервера на свою машину, получается что HEAD находится на сервере, и каждый раз приходится делать force checkout на нем для принятия изменений, когда делаю push со своей машины. Работать можно конечно. 
Но чтобы не создавать bare репозиторий, можно ли как-то дать HEAD моему компьютеру? если да, то какой командой

Comment: там, куда вы отправляете изменения командой `git push`, находится *bare-репозиторий* или всё-таки репозиторий с рабочей копией?

Comment: [дополнительно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452426/178576).

Comment: репозиторий с рабочей копией, там я делал git init, и клонировал от туда проект

Comment: значит, ссылки из моих комментариев — к месту.

Comment: почитал ссылки, но не ответил на свой вопрос. Я понимаю, что в git не очень разбираюсь, сколько не читал документации и не смотрел видео уроки, все равно для меня тяжеловато почему-то. bare репозиторий сделать можно, но написали что плохая практика. Что же делать?

Comment: кто написал и где написал, что создание bare-репозитория для отправки в него коммитов — это плохая практика? именно с использованием bare-репозиториев и происходит **вся** совместная разработка (ну, там где git вообще используется). для справки: все репозитории на github, bitbucket и т.д. и т.п. — это **исключительно** bare-репозитории.

Comment: ещё [дополнение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/178576).

Comment: Александр прав насчёт того, что bare-репозиторий это отличная практика для совместной разработки.

Comment: Если александр оформит ответ на вопрос, тогда поставлю ему галочку)   Спасибо за ответы господа