# Как определить, является ли удалённый репозиторий «голым» или с рабочей копией?

Tags: git, git-remote

Нередко для того, чтобы локализовать проблему с использованием и настройкой удалённых репозиториев в Git требуется узнать, является ли удалённый репозиторий «голым» ("bare") или обычным, имеющим рабочую копию файлов.

Разумеется, если репозиторий на GitHub, Bitbucket, Gitlab или чём-то подобном, то мы знаем точно. Также возможны решения вроде «залогиниться на сервер и посмотреть» — но далеко не всегда это возможно. Ещё можно пробовать пушить какие-либо изменения и смотреть на реакцию — но это меняет текущее состояние и тем самым усложняет проблему.

Мне нужен простой способ, который можно будет предлагать тем, от кого нужны уточнения по вопросу (например, [такому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485602/181472)).

- Обязательно не меняющий состояние удалённого и локального репозиториев
- Желательно только средствами git и ОС (без установки дополнительного ПО)
- Обходные решения не годятся («зайти и посмотреть», «спросить админа» и т.п.). Предположим, что доступа по SSH нет или пользователь не умеет это делать.

Answer (score 2):

Пока что лучшее, что я могу придумать — смотреть на имена удалённых репозиториев в их локальной фс и делать следующие предположения

- `.git` – с рабочей копией
- `name.git` – голый, bare.

Дальше смотрим на вывод `remote -v show` и вырезаем из него путь — участок между именем репозитория (под которым он настроен локально) и именем папки. Нам этот путь не интересен, а раскрывать его может быть нежелательно.

```
git remote -v show | sed s/'[[:space:]].*\/'/': '/g
```

В моих экспериментах это возвращает следующее:

С рабочей копией (склонировал из соседней папки)

```
origin: .git (fetch)
origin: .git (push)
```

Голый (склонировал из Gitlab)

```
origin: test-name.git (fetch)
origin: test-name.git (push)
```

Если репозиториев подключено несколько, то будет информация про каждый:

```
origin: .git (fetch)
origin: .git (push)
backup: .git (fetch)
backup: .git (push)
```

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`
When the repository is bare print "true", otherwise "false".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830701/how-do-i-check-if-a-repository-is-bare

Comment: Это работает относительно моего локального репозитория. А мне нужно узнать про удалённый.